# Large Forms = Large PHP/mySql Query Strings... Is There a Good Solution?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a CMS I'm building where I've got a rather large form full of data to add to my database.  This is where I collect my variables....

```
$orgName = $_POST['orgName'];
$impact = $_POST['impact'];
$headline = $_POST['headline'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$subContent = $_POST['subContent'];
$meterText = $_POST['meterText'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$shopLink = $_POST['shopLink'];
$blurbTitle = $_POST['blurbTitle'];
$blurb = $_POST['blurb'];
$logoURL = $_POST['logoURL'];
$buttonURL = $_POST['buttonURL'];
$blurbURL = $_POST['blurbURL'];
$POMURL = $_POST['POMURL'];
$horizontalURL = $_POST['horizontalURL'];
$statURL = $_POST['statURL'];
$stats = $_POST['stats'];
```

here I sql escape, validate and send to my function (omitted validation for space)...

```
require_once 'DB_Connect.php';

$connection = new DB_Connect();    

$connection->insertPartner(
    $index,
    mysql_real_escape_string($orgName),
    mysql_real_escape_string($impact),
    mysql_real_escape_string($headline),
    mysql_real_escape_string($content),
    mysql_real_escape_string($subContent),
    $month,
    mysql_real_escape_string($shopLink),
    mysql_real_escape_string($blurbTitle),
    mysql_real_escape_string($meterText),
    mysql_real_escape_string($blurb),
    mysql_real_escape_string($stats),
    mysql_real_escape_string($logoURL),
    mysql_real_escape_string($buttonURL),
    mysql_real_escape_string($blurbURL),
    mysql_real_escape_string($POMURL),
    mysql_real_escape_string($horizontalURL),
    mysql_real_escape_string($statURL)
    ))
```

and finally the function...

```
public function insertPartner(
    $orgName = '',
    $impact = '',
    $headline = '',
    $content = '',
    $subContent = '',
    $month = '',
    $shopLink = '',
    $blurbTitle = '',
    $blurb = '',
    $stats = '',
    $logoURL = '',
    $buttonURL = '',
    $blurbURL = '',
    $POMURL = '',
    $horizontalURL = '',
    $statURL = '')
    {
        $query="INSERT INTO `hupcap_FCE`.`fce_partners` (
        `index`,
        `organization_name`,
        `impact`,
        `headline`,
        `content`,
        `sub_content`,
        `blurb_title`,
        `blurb`,
        `stats`,
        `month`,
        `meter_number`,
        `meter_text`,
        `shop_link`,
        `button_img_url`,
        `blurb_img_url`,
        `logo_url`,
        `month_img_url`,
        `horizontal_logo_url`,
        `stat_img_url`,
        `util`
        ) VALUES (
        '',
        '$orgName',
        '$impact',
        '$headline',
        '$content',
        '$subContent',
        '$blurbTitle',
        '$blurb',
        '$stats',
        '$month',
        0,
        '',
        '$shopLink',
        '$buttonURL',
        '$blurbURL',
        '$logoURL',
        '$POMURL',
        '$horizontalURL',
        '$statURL',
        0)";
        if(mysql_query($query)){
            return true;
        }else{
            die("failed to insert record" . mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

There has GOT to be a slicker way of doing this.
Who's got the best method?

Thanks -J

Comment: As a suggestion, as a rule of thumb, the max number of values for parameter passing is around 7 or 8. You have 15.

Comment: @Anthony Forloney I had no idea there was a rule of thumb regarding parameter passing... I suppose an Array is a better option?

Comment: The rule of thumb regarding parameter passing isn't a life or death situation, its more of a convention that people adapt to. An array would be an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option #1**

Use an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) to handle CRUD in your PHP apps.

**Option #2**

If using an ORM is too big of a paradigm shift try something like this:

```
// Alias $_POST fields to SQL columns
$sql_columns= array(
    'post_field1'=> 'sql_column1',
    'post_field2'=> 'sql_column2',
    'post_field3'=> 'sql_column3');

// Encode $_POST data for use in SQL
$sql_a= array();
foreach ($sql_columns as $k=> $k2) {
 if (isset($_POST[$k])) {
  $sql_a[]= sprintf("`%s` = '%s'", $k2, mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$k]));
 }
}

// Build SQL string to execute
$sql= sprintf('INSERT INTO table_name SET %s', implode(', ', $sql_a));
var_dump($sql);
```

This can easily be extended into a function or a class to handle different tables, columns and SQL statements.

Comment: man, now I gotta look up what the hell sprintf is.  I looked at the ORM Doctrine.  I'm just finally feeling comfortable with writing PHP classes. I'm down to go there, but I'd say I'm at least six months from adding ORM to my pallet.  And, if I'm not mistaken, it looks as though it's something I'd need installed?  I rent server space from Hostgator, I'm lucky I get phpMyAdmin.  (Actually, they haven't been bad to me).  Thank you for your response.  I'm sure once I understand it, I'll be happy about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

do a foreach to run all over the params array, so you can check the value. Do some magic inside the final function so you can check if any of them is empty or something...

Comment: hmm, i could not get this, is he trying to remove empty fields?

Comment: he is looking for a better way of doing this or probably shorten the code and get some speed :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have 16 columns in your table, you're going to have a long insert statement.

You should use one of the database wrapper classes (like PDO). Firstly, it gives you a convenient way use prepared statements (avoiding SQL injection, and adding type checking). Secondly, it makes adding parameters more readable, since you don't have to concatenate one huge string.

```
function insert_stuff($col1, $col2, $col3) {
    $conn = new PDO($connectionString);
    $query = "insert into my_table (col1, col2, col3) values (:col1, :col2, :col3)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);

    $statement->bindValue(":col1", $col1);
    $statement->bindValue(":col2", $col2);
    $statement->bindValue(":col3", $col3);

    $statement->execute();
    // etc. 
}
```

If you're really bothered by all the typing, you can use your database to generate some of the code for you:

```
select 
    concat('$statement->bindValue(":', column_name, '", $', column_name, ');' 
from
    information_schema.columns
where
    table_schema = 'my_database_name'
and table_name = 'my_table_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
$insertArray() = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key=> $name)
{
    $insertArray[$name] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$name]);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO `hupcap_FCE`.`fce_partners` (" . implode(',', array_keys($insertArray)) VALUES '" . implode("','", $insertArray) . "'";

//...
```

THIS IS NOT SECURE BUT IT WOULD WORK :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it seems to be how it should be *for the most part*, however, you can save your life to a great extent by doing this:

Instead of writing:

```
$orgName = $_POST['orgName'];
$impact = $_POST['impact'];
$headline = $_POST['headline'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$subContent = $_POST['subContent'];
$meterText = $_POST['meterText'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$shopLink = $_POST['shopLink'];
$blurbTitle = $_POST['blurbTitle'];
$blurb = $_POST['blurb'];
$logoURL = $_POST['logoURL'];
$buttonURL = $_POST['buttonURL'];
$blurbURL = $_POST['blurbURL'];
$POMURL = $_POST['POMURL'];
$horizontalURL = $_POST['horizontalURL'];
$statURL = $_POST['statURL'];
$stats = $_POST['stats'];
```

You could simply write this line:

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);
```

And now you have all the same variables available like what you did with so many lines above, for example, now you can use them or echo them:

```
echo $orgName;
echo $impact;
echo $headline;
```

**To Add:** I am not sure  whether using `extract` is good practice in terms of security, however, i have been using this without any problems so far :)

Comment: By default `extract` will overwrite existing variables. At the very least call it like this `extract($a, EXTR_SKIP)` to prevent an attacker from foobaring your existing code.

Comment: @pygorex - right on, imagine if there was a variable $isAdmin or something, and someone POSTed "isAdmin" with a value of "true"... Anyway, this doesn't really help the OP because the values still are not sanitized.

Comment: love the extract function. Will be happy to be using that in the near future.